# python list iterate,concat performance issue

Tags: python

I write a simple insert sort function by two ways.

```
def binary_search(the_array, item, start, end):
    if start == end:
        if the_array[start] > item:
            return start
        else:
            return start + 1
    if start > end:
        return start

    mid = round((start + end)/ 2)

    if the_array[mid] < item:
        return binary_search(the_array, item, mid + 1, end)

    elif the_array[mid] > item:
        return binary_search(the_array, item, start, mid - 1)

    else:
        return mid

def insertion_sort(the_array):
    l = len(the_array)
    start = time.process_time()   
    for index in range(1, l):
        value = the_array[index]
        pos = binary_search(the_array, value, 0, index - 1)
        #Way A:
        #for p in range(index,pos,-1):
        #    the_array[p] = the_array[p-1]   
        #the_array[pos] = value
        #Way B:
        #the_array = the_array[:pos] + [value] + the_array[pos:index] + the_array[index+1:]
    end = time.process_time()
    print("Cost time:",end-start)
    return the_array
```

A:

```
 for p in range(index,pos,-1):
     the_array[p] = the_array[p-1]   
 the_array[pos] = value
```

B:

```
the_array = the_array[:pos] + [value] + the_array[pos:index] + the_array[index+1:]
```

I am not good at python.In my performance test B way is fast than A way.I use python **time.process_time** for get time offset.

**So the question why B way fast than A way?**  Please help me.Thanks

UPDATE:
I use 10000 random int to test A and B.

```
for x in range(0,10000):
    data.append(random.randint(0,10000))
```

A way cost 2.3125s B way cost 0.890625s.

One day later, no answer tell me **why**,So I decide to read a book about this.In "High Performance Python" I found the answer for **why**!If you want to know you could see my own answer.

Comment: please, fix your indentation

Comment: what is your goal? write a insert method in a array that is already sorted and keep it sorted?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov fixed

Comment: @B.Almeida sorry for late reply.I use random integers in list and sort them. and test the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why iterating over a range slow than list concatenate?

It has two reason as follow:

1. In python iterating over a range can not perform [Automatic Vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization).Operations execute one by one. CPU wastes time for waitting memory operation.
2. Python list store the pointer of data not data itself.So each time we access the data by using index that we perform extra indirectly operation.It is not cache friendly.

So although concatenate list will alloc more memory,but it operate memory entirely   rather than one by one.CPU don't waste time for waitting memory operation.

I found a **Pythonic** way to do this job.

```
the_array[pos+1:index+1] = the_array[pos:index]
the_array[pos] = value
```

It is faster than A and B.And still very easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a very high-level, interpreted language. In exchange to simplicity and readability, trivial tasks liking iterating the `range` generator may add a perceivable overhead.

In contrast, list comprehension and slicing is implemented with high performance.

Although they differ only by a constant factor, you can actually get faster:

```
import random
import time 

def binary_search(the_array, item, start, end):
    if start == end:
        if the_array[start] > item:
            return start
        else:
            return start + 1
    if start > end:
        return start

    mid = round((start + end)/ 2)

    if the_array[mid] < item:
        return binary_search(the_array, item, mid + 1, end)

    elif the_array[mid] > item:
        return binary_search(the_array, item, start, mid - 1)

    else:
        return mid

def insertion_sort_a(the_array):
    l = len(the_array)
    start = time.process_time()   
    for index in range(1, l):
        value = the_array[index]
        pos = binary_search(the_array, value, 0, index - 1)
        for p in range(index,pos,-1):
           the_array[p] = the_array[p-1]   
        the_array[pos] = value
    end = time.process_time()
    print("Cost time:",end-start,end="\t")
    return the_array

def insertion_sort_b(the_array):
    l = len(the_array)
    start = time.process_time()   
    for index in range(1, l):
        value = the_array[index]
        pos = binary_search(the_array, value, 0, index - 1)
        the_array = the_array[:pos] + [value] + the_array[pos:index] + the_array[index+1:]
    end = time.process_time()
    print(end-start, end="\t")
    return the_array

def insertion_sort_c(the_array):
    l = len(the_array)
    start = time.process_time()   
    for index in range(1, l):
        value = the_array[index]
        while index > 0 and the_array[index-1] > value:
            the_array[index] = the_array[index-1]
            index -= 1
        the_array[index] = value
    end = time.process_time()
    print(end-start, end="\t")
    return the_array

def insertion_sort_d(the_array):
    l = len(the_array)
    start = time.process_time()   
    for index in range(1, l):
        value = the_array[index]
        pos = binary_search(the_array, value, 0, index - 1)
        the_array[pos+1:index+1] = the_array[pos:index]
        the_array[pos] = value
    end = time.process_time()
    print(end-start)
    return the_array

for n in range(20):
    n = 2**n
    data = []
    for x in range(0,n):
        data.append(random.randint(0,n))

    a = insertion_sort_a(list(data))
    assert all(a[i] <= a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1))
    b = insertion_sort_b(list(data))
    assert all(b[i] <= b[i+1] for i in range(len(b)-1))
    c = insertion_sort_c(list(data))
    assert all(c[i] <= c[i+1] for i in range(len(c)-1))
    d = insertion_sort_d(list(data))
    assert all(d[i] <= d[i+1] for i in range(len(d)-1))

    assert a == b
    assert b == c
    assert c == d
```

Comment: I test the code. insertion_sort_c is worse than all others.  insertion_sort_d is best.So reason is not range generator cost time. For real reason see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming method A and B are giving the same results, method A has to iterate over a range while method B is a simple assignment -- so of course method B will be faster.

This is a nested for loop under an existing for loop (probably O(n<sup>2</sup>) worst case):

```
for p in range(index,pos,-1):
    the_array[p] = the_array[p-1]
```

This is a straight assignment under one for loop:

```
the_array = the_array[:pos] + [value] + the_array[pos:index] + the_array[index+1:]
```

Without running this, I'm assuming the two are giving the same results -- but iterating over a range vs. a straight assignment will always be slower.